# AutoCompleteTextview with Recyclerview with custom filtering

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, filtering, autocompletetextview

I am working on an app that lets patients consult with doctors remotely, currently, I am working in an activity where I need to filter various departments based on the symptoms typed by the patient. The existing UI already works with the department name filtering however, now I will to custom filtering.
For instance, if the patient types "fever or common cold", the general medicine department should come on top

[image: UI of the activity]

Comment: ok what is the proplem?

Comment: the problem is the symptoms aren't coming from the API like the other data they are basically hardcoded and I have to add multifilter as user search by dept or symptoms

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain department names globally, and use them inside `onBindViewHolder`. Whenever user types, you can modify the global array and call `notifydatasetchanged`.